# Eclipse Luna does not find references to Java elements

Tags: java, eclipse

In the Java editor I right-click on a method name or class name or other element (defined in my source, not in a dependency JAR) and from the menu I select References / Workspace.

In some cases the references to such elements are found and shown in the Search view as expected. But in most cases no reference is found, which I know is wrong because those elements are definitely referenced by some code in projects found in the workspace (and if I do a File search they are always found, and if I Ctrl-click on the reference, f.ex. a method call, I'm taken to the method body as expected).

It makes no difference if instead of using the menu item References / Workspace I select the element in the code and hit Ctrl+Shift+G, or right-click on the element in the Outline view and use the menu item References / Workspace from there.

No project in the workspace has compilation errors and all the projects run normally.
The projects are all set to use Java 7 JDK ("C:\glassfish4\jdk7").

In another post about Juno I found mentions to an Index Rebuild feature, but I couldn't find anything index-related in Luna preferences.

When I was using Eclipse Kepler instead of Luna I was searching for references in exactly the same ways and the references were always found correctly. Actually this problem occurred with Kepler too for a short period but then it went away and I never understood why. But now with Luna this problem is there since the beginning and it seems to be there to stay.

The version of Luna is 4.4.0.I20140606-1215. I added to it the same  plugins I had in Kepler: Subclipse, TapestryTools, FindBugs, ResourceBundle Editor, TestNG.

I could not find any Preferences setting that appears to me to be affecting this.

I'm wondering if other people are experiencing the same problem and if there is a known cause, solution or workaround.

UPDATE 2015-08-21: Switched to Eclipse Mars (added same plugins), problem still there.

UPDATE 2016-07-27: Switched to Eclipse Neon (added same plugins), problem seems no longer there. It's been less than a month though, so I'll wait a few months before I celebrate, also because the [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=108749) on eclipse.org is still in status "new" and doesn't mention any solution (or anything else at all since 10 months). If I notice the problem again I will update here.

Comment: The above applies to workspaces created with Luna. Interestingly, I just opened in Luna a workspace that had been created with Kepler. Luna prompted me that the workspace would be converted; then I searched for the very same references and they were found.

Comment: Also, if I go to menu Navigate / Open Type (or Ctrl+Shift+T) and in the Open Type dialog I enter the name of a class that certainly exists, very often it is not shown under Matching items (so I cannot open the class in that way). But if I go to menu Navigate / Open Resource (or Ctrl+Shift+R) instead, and I enter exactly the same name, it is found, and I can open the class in that way. It definitely sounds like another manifestation of the same issue.

Comment: Got an answer at eclipse.org; https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/814360/

Comment: Can you please let know what steps did you do to make it work? I'm also facing the same problem.

Comment: @geekprogrammer I just did what is mentioned in the eclipse.org thread I linked. That is, `shut down Eclipse, and from the .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core directory in that workspace, delete *.index, indexNamesMap.txt, and savedIndexNames.txt.`.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same but that didnd't work for me. So just wanted to know if you did anything additional. Anyway, Thanks.

Comment: @geekprogrammer That's strange, I did it tens of times on different computers and it always worked. Those files are definitely the ones where those "indexes" are stored, so if deleting them doesn't help (and that is done in the right workspace folder) it can only mean that those files get recreated wrong right away. I suggest you to try again if you didn't already.

Comment: Not sure if I should report my own question as a duplicate :p but I found [a much older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166849/fix-eclipse-java-references-database-corruption) about this same problem. And from it I found that this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=108749) is surviving since 10 years at least.

Comment: OK. Thanks for pointing this out. This is actually a big problem than it looks like. In short, the references feature is unreliable, because one don't know if the index has been corrupted. In my case I believed Eclipse, made some changes and committed the code; I came to know that there were indeed some references to the code I had changed only after the main buld failed :(

Comment: @geekprogrammer I strongly agree that this is a big problem and I'm genuinely astonished that this bug is not taken as seriously as it would deserve in my opinion, considering how badly it can mislead developers without them having a chance of noticing except sheer luck. I really love Eclipse but this kind of things just blow my mind. Seeing how long this bug has been there - and the scarce interest there seems to be in fixing it - makes my nose bleed. Whatever.

Comment: @SantiBailors This *is* taken seriously. There are efforts at Google at doing something about this, and they had a talk at EclipseCon a few weeks about this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Bc97sHiy2lZmFPc210SXFDRU0/view

Comment: @JesperE Thanks for the info and for the link. My impression of a scarce interest in fixing this was mainly due to the 10+ years thing. So this is great news.

Comment: @JesperE 4+ years later and my Eclipse 2020-06 (4.16) can't find any references.

Comment: @JesperE Even though I'm not sure why an Eclipse bug is expected to be fixed by Google, how did that go ? Still "taken seriously" ? Not only it's 4 years since your last comment, it's also 15 years since the bug was reported. This is a very severe bug, and it acts silently, it can screw up big time and that may be found out much later. If this is how Eclipse takes things "seriously" I wonder how long they take for less severe problems.

Comment: I have no idea how it is going, having left the Eclipse plugin development ecosystem 2 years ago. I suspect that the Google effort to improve the Eclipse java indexer was abandoned, but I really don't know.