# Open implementation acts like open type hierarchy in eclipse, why?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

Please help me with that. I verify the shorcuts and the Key and it`s ok for Open Implementation and for Type Hierachy. About a week ago, i had the same problem and i solved it with a restart, but now  -no.

ps. if i open another workspace it works.

Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)

Comment: Is the implementation unique?

Comment: This might be caused by some corrupted cache. If you don't want to just create a new workspace, you can try to manually clean some cached indexes as explained in comment "2005-09-05 04:47:27 EDT"  of [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=108749) eclipse.org bug report (and perhaps also vote for it as it's still in status "New"). You might get lucky. It's worth a shot as it's harmless and easy to do.

Comment: Also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1167030/2814308) details more ways to clean indexes in Eclipse (they will be rebuilt, so harmless).

Comment: I solved the problem with an another restart, but that not work every time. Next time  i will try your solution and i come back with an answer. Thanks.